# Randomize questions in a multiple choice game

Tags: java, android-studio

I made a multiple choice game and tried to randomize the questions by using the shuffle method on my array which contains all my questions. The problem is that some questions are being constantly repeated, so you will see some questions two times, some you won't see at all. 
I thought that I could use a arraylist instead of an array, so I could use the remove method after a question has been asked, but I Always get Errors with the arraylist and I don't even know if my approach makes sense. You can see my problem under that big chunk full of objects, in the ShuffleQuestions method and the ShowNextQuestion method.

How would you go on about this problem? Thank you for your help!

Here's my Code:

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView mImageView;
TextView mTextView;
TextView mAnswer;
TextView score;
TextView countDown;
Button opt1;
Button opt2;
Button opt3;
Button opt4;


public static final long COUNTDOWN_IN_MILLISECODS = 30000;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private long timeLeftInMilliseconds;
private ColorStateList textColorDefaultCd;

int scoreNumber = 0;
int questionNumber;
int questionNumberTotal = 10;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mTextView = findViewById(R.id.tvQ);
    mAnswer = findViewById(R.id.tvA);
    score = findViewById(R.id.tvScore);
    countDown = findViewById(R.id.tvCd);
    opt1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    opt2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    opt3 = findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    opt4 = findViewById(R.id.btn4);

    textColorDefaultCd = countDown.getTextColors();

    ShowNewQuestion();
    StartCountDown();

opt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(opt1.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText()))
        {
            ShowNewQuestion();
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "yes" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            scoreNumber++;
            questionNumber++;
            UpdateScore();
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            StartCountDown();
        }
        else {

            ShowNewQuestion();
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "No" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            questionNumber++;
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            StartCountDown();

        }
    }
});

    opt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(opt2.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText()))
            {
                ShowNewQuestion();
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "yes" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                scoreNumber++;
                questionNumber++;
                UpdateScore();
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                StartCountDown();
            }

            else {

                ShowNewQuestion();
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "No" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                questionNumber++;
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                StartCountDown();

            }
        }
    });

    opt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(opt3.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText()))
            {
                ShowNewQuestion();
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "yes" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                scoreNumber++;
                questionNumber++;
                UpdateScore();
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                StartCountDown();
            }

            else {

                ShowNewQuestion();
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "No" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                questionNumber++;
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                StartCountDown();

            }
        }
    });
    opt4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(opt4.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText()))
            {
                ShowNewQuestion();
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "yes" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                scoreNumber++;
                questionNumber++;
                UpdateScore();
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                StartCountDown();
            }

            else {

                ShowNewQuestion();
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "No" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                questionNumber++;
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                StartCountDown();

            }
        }
    });
}
Objects q01 = new Objects(R.drawable.blauwahl, "Das Herz eines Blauwals ist ungefähr so groß wie...", "ein VW-Käfer", "Angela Merkels Privatjet", "ein VW-Käfer", "eine Vespa", "eine Wassermelone" );
Objects q02 = new Objects(R.drawable.simbabwe, "Der südafrikanische Staat Simbabwe wurde 1980 unabhängig. Wie hieß das Land früher? ", "Rhodesien", "Botswana", "Rhodesien", "Südafrika", "Botsuana" );
Objects q03 = new Objects(R.drawable.sonnenkoenig, " Der französische Sonnenkönig Ludwig XIV. herrschte lange Jahre über Frankreich. Wie viele? ", "72", "22", "52", "62", "72");
Objects q04 = new Objects(R.drawable.tempelberg, "Der Tempelberg in Jerusalem ist rund 144.000 Quadratmeter groß und beladen mit Mythen. Wer soll hier den ersten Mord der Menschheit begangen haben?", "Kain", "David", "Kain", "Herodes", "Joseph" );
Objects q05 = new Objects(R.drawable.frauenkirche, "In welchem Jahr des Zweiten Weltkrieges wurde die Dresdener Frauenkirche zerstört? ", "1945", "1943", "1944", "1945", "1939");
Objects q06 = new Objects(R.drawable.kueste, "Welches dieser europäischen Länder hat die längste Küste?", "Griechenland", "Italien", "Griechenland", "Frankreich", "Türkei" );
Objects q07 = new Objects(R.drawable.umriss, "Der Umriss welches inselreichen Landes ist hier zu sehen?", "Dänemark", "Dänemark", "Philippinen", "Kroatien", "Griechenland" );
Objects q08 = new Objects(R.drawable.blitz, "Woran liegt es, dass man den Donner bei manchen Blitzen erst viel später hört als bei anderen?", "An der unterschiedlichen Entfernung der Blitze", "An der unterschiedlichen Entfernung der Blitze", "An der Stärke der elektrischen Entladungen", "An der Dichte des Regens", "An den heftigen Windböen");
Objects q09 = new Objects(R.drawable.biathlon, "Aus welchen beiden Disziplinen setzt sich ein Biathlon zuammen?", "Sportschießen und Skilanglauf", "Sportschießen und Skilanglauf", " Skispringen und Skilanglauf ", " Skilanglauf und Abfahrtslauf ", "Abfahrtslauf und Skispringen " );
Objects q10 = new Objects(R.drawable.licht, "In welcher physikalischen Einheit wird die Lichtstärke gemessen?", "Candela", "Joule", "Lumen", "Lux", "Candela" );


Objects [] objectsArray = new Objects[]{
        q01,q02,q03,q04,q05,q06,q07,q08,q09,q10
};



public  void shuffleQuestions(){

    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(objectsArray));
}

public void ShowNewQuestion () {
    if(questionNumber < questionNumberTotal) {
        shuffleQuestions();
        mTextView.setText(objectsArray[0].getmQuestion());
        mImageView.setImageResource(objectsArray[0].getmImages());
        opt1.setText(objectsArray[0].getmOption1());
        opt2.setText(objectsArray[0].getmOption2());
        opt3.setText(objectsArray[0].getmOption3());
        opt4.setText(objectsArray[0].getmOption4());
        mAnswer.setText(objectsArray[0].getmAnswer());

        timeLeftInMilliseconds = COUNTDOWN_IN_MILLISECODS;


    }
    else {
        FinishQuiz();
    }
}

void StartCountDown(){
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMilliseconds, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            timeLeftInMilliseconds = millisUntilFinished;
            UpdateCountdownText();


        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timeLeftInMilliseconds = 0;
            ShowNewQuestion();
            StartCountDown();

        }
    }.start();
}

void UpdateCountdownText(){
    int minutes = (int)(timeLeftInMilliseconds / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds = (int)(timeLeftInMilliseconds / 1000) % 60;

    String timeFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

    countDown.setText(timeFormatted);

    if (timeLeftInMilliseconds < 10000) {
        countDown.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else
    {
        countDown.setTextColor(textColorDefaultCd);
    }
}

public void UpdateScore()
{
    score.setText("Score:" + scoreNumber);
}

void FinishQuiz (){

        Intent i  = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle  = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("finalScore", scoreNumber);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        QuizActivity.this.finish();
        startActivity(i);
    }



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (countDownTimer != null)
    {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
       }
    }
}
```

Here I'm saving the objects:

```
public class Objects {

public int mImages;
public String mQuestion;
public String mAnswer;
public String mOption1;
public String mOption2;
public String mOption3;
public String mOption4;


public Objects(int mImages, String mQuestion, String mAnswer, String mOption1, String mOption2, String mOption3, String mOption4) {
    this.mImages = mImages;
    this.mQuestion = mQuestion;
    this.mAnswer = mAnswer;
    this.mOption1 = mOption1;
    this.mOption2 = mOption2;
    this.mOption3 = mOption3;
    this.mOption4 = mOption4;
    this.mAnswer = mAnswer;

}

public int getmImages() {

    return mImages;
}

public String getmQuestion() {
    return mQuestion;
}

public String getmAnswer() {
    return mAnswer;
}

public String getmOption1() {

    return mOption1;
}

public String getmOption2() {

    return mOption2;
}

public String getmOption3() {

    return mOption3;
}

public String getmOption4() {

    return mOption4;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shuffle the question every time; that's the wrong way to go about it.

Shuffle *ONCE* only, then maintain a pointer into the structure; it starts at 0 and everytime you render a question, up it. This way, you walk through the entire array of questions precisely once, hitting every question exactly once, and the one-time sorting ensures that it'll be a uniform different order every time you go through.